# Swing: overwrite setSize or use ComponentAdapter.componentResized?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, resize

I have seen several places that a `JComponent`-descendant should listen for `ComponentAdapter.componentResized` if it is interested in its resize events.

And I wonder: what is the difference, if any, if I simply override `setSize(...)`?

It seems that using a listener on the descendant component directly makes sense only if you want to clearly document the use of that interface. However, others' use of an inner class for capturing this event is more logical and it does not pollute the source of the main class.

Also, if I resize programmatically, then `setSize` will trigger the `componentResized` event. So why is listening to the resize event notification is so popular?

Comment: There is a difference between a method that changes a property, and an event listener

Comment: Duly noted. But I think any action to be done "on resize" by the component itself (as a direct effect of the resize) should be in `setSize()` and not *eventually* be done in an event handler... But I may be wrong :-)

Comment: It could be a matter of preference or typical "java coding etiquette" because both give a similar resulting effect.